# Play a previously uploaded mp3 in a django 1.10 template

Tags: html, django, audio

Ok, the basics. mate desktop on linux mint, Python 3.5.2 django 1.10, not that I think any of those details is going to be relevant. I think I'm doing something very basic wrong with my html. I can't play a local mp3 file, either directly hard coded, with either an absolute path or a relative path, or by passing the path to the file via a method that works for the rest of my data.

I can play an mp3 from the net, with this in my template`

```
    <p>
    <audio controls
    src="https://soundbible.com/mp3/Tyrannosaurus%20Rex%20Roar-SoundBible.com-807702404.mp3">
    </audio>
```

That works fine. This same template can take data entered in my form and pass it to the template to be displayed in the browser via:

`<p style="margin-left: 40px">{{ post.published_date }}</p>`

The {{ post.published_date }} does retrieve the data it's supposed to, in fact everything else works fine, dozens of inputs work exactly as I expect them to. So likely not problems with my models or forms. The file upload I use in the form seems to be working fine, as I can manually confirm the file is there within the folder structure I've specified. documents/Year/month/day/file.mp3.

I can confirm that post.docfile (method I use  to grab the specific mp3 I want) does point exactly to the file I want, but I get a:

`/post/3/documents/2018/08/30/file.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 3020`

error when the html is trying to play the file with `<audio>`.

So evidently my template can play a random mp3 from the net, with a http:// type address but can't play any local mp3, even with a directly coded hard path to the mp3, nor can it play a file with what I think is the correct file path passed to it via post.docfile, when all my other post method data does get passed correctly.

I've checked the ownership of the files, and it's my regular user name that owns all the directories and files from top to bottom, not root or anything else. I've checked the permissions, and saw that my uploaded mp3's couldn't be executed, or written, so I changed the permissions to 755, though that shouldn't have had any effect and in fact did not.

Some other details I suspect are not relevant, using chrome, on my local laptop. sqlite3 is my db. This isn't homework, I'm just trying to solve some small biz problems for my wife. I've adapted some blog type django tutorials to throw something together for her, and the rest of it is working fine.

Thank you for taking a min to point me in the right direction.

I'm hoping you guys won't say you need my models and forms to help, that I'm just doing something basic wrong in html. Thanks much

`

Comment: Using the `<audio>` tag is not different than downloading the same file using any other method. The file needs to be accessible. That URL looks wrong as it should most likely be served from your `media` directory. What do you get when  you try to visit http://localhost:8080/post/3/documents/2018/08/30/file.mp3 (correct the localhost:8080 part according to your configuration)?

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Tried it, and variations of it. First got a `Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'localhost:8000'. You may need to add 'localhost' to ALLOWED_HOSTS 12HTTP/1.1" 400' error, which I fixed by adding localhost to ALLOWED in settings.py. 127.0.0.1 was already there, so I tried http://127.0.0.1/path/to/file.mp3, which lead to a 404 error instead of 400. I did add  `MEDIA_URL = '/documents/'`
` MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'documents')` to my settings.py a while ago, didn't seem to make a difference. Thank you for the ideas.

Comment: Post your latest settings, view, and template code please.

Comment: Also from that `400` error it looks like you have not enabled `DEBUG` in your `settings.py`. You can't serve media files using the development server when `DEBUG` is set to `False`.